# Simple function not working when using namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, cout

I have the below code that compiles and executes without error, but the line that should be printed in the menu() function is never printed.

Menu.cpp

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Menu.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace View
{
 void Menu::startMenu()
    {
    cout << "2\n";
    }
}
```

Menu.hpp

```
#ifndef MENU_H //"Header guard"
#define MENU_H

namespace View
{
class Menu
    {
    void startMenu();
    };
}
#endif
```

I wrote a simple test to call the menu function, if it works correctly the output should be
1
2
3

but the 2 is never printed.

MenuTest.cpp

```
#include "Menu.hpp"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "1\n";
    View::Menu startMenu();
    cout << "3\n";
}
```

Can someone see what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
View::Menu startMenu();
```

Declares a function which returns View::Menu type, which is also known as [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

To initialize an object and call it's member function, you should do:

```
View::Menu menu;
menu.startMenu();
```

BTW, you need to make startMenu() function public:

```
class Menu
{
public:    //<-----
    void startMenu();
};
```

See [live sample](http://ideone.com/mGyp4S).
help this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I understand much better now. I was treating it more like C, I have to think in terms of objects now.

Comment: I should include the "Menu.cpp" in MenuTest.cpp, or I get an error:

Comment: @minicaptain do not include .cpp file, instead you should include .hpp and link .cpp

Answer (score 1):

When substracting the brckets of `View::Menu startMenu();`, the code

```
View::Menu startMenu;
```

is a object definition of View::Menu, which does not call the function Menu::startMenu(). And that is when `"cout << "2\n";"` is not executed. To call further `Menu::startMenu()`:

```
startMenu.startMenu();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you declare function "startMenu()", that is returns type "View:Menu"
But you don't call function startMenu().

Try make following code:

```
View::Menu obj;
obj.startMenu();
```

PS. And make startMenu() as public:

```
class Menu
{
    public:
        void startMenu();
};
```